# Create DIV in the line below after DIV with float left

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two others divs inside with the float: left; property. I want to go in the new line with the next div.

I tried to put width: 100%; in the two divs but nothing changed.

[image]

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div class="img-head">
    <img src="/nutickets2/images/evento-1.png">
</div>
<div class="text-head-div">
    <span class="text-head">HYPER Festival LAUNCH PARTY</span><br><br><br>

        <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Steve Jobs</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
                <th>Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 100;">
    <div>NEXT DIV TESTTTTTTT</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-head {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.text-head-div {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.text-head {
    color: #0099cc;
}

.text-head-1 {
    color: #000000;
}

.text-head-2 {
    color: #000000;
}

.table-1 th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 19px;
}
```

Comment: try tu use clearfix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `clear:both;`. That will force the element drop below. Also note that when you specify width property, it's mandatory to mention the unit.

```
<div style="width:100px; clear:both;">
    <div>NEXT DIV TESTTTTTTT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: left` to the second DIV, that's enough (it interrupts the floating)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```css
.img-head {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.text-head-div {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.text-head {
    color: #0099cc;
}

.text-head-1 {
    color: #000000;
}

.text-head-2 {
    color: #000000;
}

.table-1 th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 19px;
}
.first:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="first" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="img-head">
    <img src="/nutickets2/images/evento-1.png">
</div>
<div class="text-head-div">
    <span class="text-head">HYPER Festival LAUNCH PARTY</span><br><br><br>

        <table class="table-1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Bill Gates</td>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <td>Steve Jobs</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
                <th>Telephone:</th>
                <td>55577854</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="next">
    <div>NEXT DIV TESTTTTTTT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is great that you are helping and providing some code but it is usually more helpful to tell the person just the information they need to know. This both helps the OP learn and will help others in the future who are looking for an answer but don't want to dig through lines and lines of code.